# Troubles with 'Either' in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use 'Either' in Haskell to get the *right* value. It is usually easy to do, but I'm getting an error, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

What I want to do is this:

```
 cropImage image = do
    resized  <- resizeImage copy        
    newImage <- getImageFromEither resized
    ...
```

where `resized` is defined as:

`resized :: Either CV.CvException (M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]) channels depth)`

And I want to get `M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]) channels depth`

to do it, I use this function:

```
getImageFromEither eitherImage = fromRight eitherImage
```

and:

```
fromRight :: Either a b -> b
fromRight (Left _)  = error "fromRight: Argument takes form 'Left _'"
fromRight (Right x) = x
```

And I thought it should work. But I get this error:

```
    Couldn't match kind ‘*’ with ‘CV.DS *'
    When matching types
      m :: * -> *
      M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]) channels :: CV.DS * -> *
    Expected type: Either CV.CvException (m t0)
      Actual type: Either
                     CV.CvException (M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]) channels depth)
    Relevant bindings include
      resized :: Either
                   CV.CvException (M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]) channels depth)
        (bound at src/CropImage.hs:25:9)
      copy :: M.Mat ('CV.S '[height, width]) channels depth
        (bound at src/CropImage.hs:32:17)
      image :: M.Mat ('CV.S '[height, width]) channels depth
        (bound at src/CropImage.hs:24:11)
      cropImage :: M.Mat ('CV.S '[height, width]) channels depth
                   -> m (Either
                           CV.CvException (M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]) channels depth))
        (bound at src/CropImage.hs:24:1)
    In the first argument of ‘getImageFromEither’, namely ‘resized’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: newImage <- getImageFromEither resized
```

I don't have an idea what's wrong. I see the code right, but I'm blind with the error.

Comment: If `resized` has type `Either CV.CvException (M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D])` you're saying `resizeImage` returns an `Either e (Either CV.CvException (M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]))`? Or does `resizeImage` return an `Either CV.CvException (M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D])`? In that case `resized` is a `(M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D])`

Comment: @Lee Thank you for your answer. `resizeImage` returns an `Either CV.CvException (M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D])`. But, as you can see in the error message, resized is an `Either CV.CvException (M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D])` Isn't it?

Comment: If you have an expression `x` of type `Either e a` then within `do` notation, in `v <- x`, `v` has type `a`. So that means `resized` has type `M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]` and you don't need to use `getImageFromEither`. Does it work if you use `newImage <- resizeImage copy`?

Comment: @Lee Nope, I got this error `Couldn't match expected type ‘M.Mat shape0 channels0 depth0’ with actual type ‘Either CV.CvException (M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]) channels depth)’` . It means that `resized` isn't `M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]) channels depth` :(

Comment: @Lee But if I do this: `case resized of Left cvError -> print ("nope") Right image -> do putStrLn (show (getHandW image))`. It works, but I need it in a function an get `image` back (getHanW returns the image shape, it was just an example.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely want

```
cropImage image = do
    resized  <- resizeImage copy        
    let newImage = getImageFromEither resized
    ...
```

Remember that `<-` is used to run monadic actions, and `let .. = ..` is used to define pure values. Here, `getImageFromEither` has not a monadic return type -- it does not perform any action in the monad, it is a plain, regular function.

Also consider the possibility of handling both cases explicitly:

```
cropImage image = do
    resized  <- resizeImage copy
    case resized of
      Left err -> error ("resize failed: " ++ show err)
      Right newImage -> do
         ...
```

This also allows you to handle the error more gracefully, e.g. by reporting it to the user. Using `error` or a partial function like your `getImageFromEither` is not generally considered good style. Handling errors by crashing is convenient in the short term, but eventually you'll likely want that error to be handled properly.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. Just a thing. I would like to use the second way, but it doesn't work for me as I need _return newImage_ at some time. When I write `Right newImage -> do` and then `return newImage`, it says `Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘M.Mat ('CV.S '['CV.D, 'CV.D]) channels depth’` So, how could I return _newImage_ ?

Comment: `return newImage` looks correct... are you sure you declared `cropImage` to return `IO (M.Mat ...)` and not `IO ()` ? I wonder why the expected type is `IO ()` there according to the error.

Comment: I can `return newImage` if I write `let newImage = ...` but I can't return it if I write it inside the `case ... of... ` I don't know why.

Comment: Can you post your new code snippet somewhere? It's hard to tell otherwise.

Comment: @ChuckAguilar My best guess is that you are accidentally returning `IO ()` in the `Left` branch, and both branches must have the same type. The compiler complains that the second does not match the first, while it's actually the first one which does not match the second. (Wild guessing here...)

Comment: Here's the code. [code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_haskell_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMWXNER050VVZzS0k )

Comment: Indeed both branches must return something (of the same type). So either in the first branch you use something like `error`, or you have to return the error to the caller. The latter means that the return type is not `IO M.Mat` but something like `IO (Maybe M.Mat)` or `IO (Either ...)`.